# PHP DOM-XPath on a Table

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to extract data from a table using...

```
   $tags = $xpath->query('//tr[@valign="top"]/td/span[@style="background-color:#cccccc;font-weight:bold;"]');
```

on a row that looks like...

```
   <tr valign="top">
                <td style="background-color:#cccccc;"><span style="background-color:#cccccc;font-weight:bold;">Some Company</span>
```

But its not retrieving the data, it works using the DOM inspector in firebug... using the xpath...

```
     $tags = $xpath->query('//tr[@valign="top"]/td/span');
```

works but it pulls other data not wanted.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible there is some ordering/formatting issue with those `style` properties? Try the following:

```
//tr[@valign="top"]/td/span[contains(@style, 'background-color:#cccccc') and 
                            contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]
```

You could also try selecting based on the contents of the cell (assuming the value is unique):

```
//tr[@valign="top"]/td/span[.='Some Company']
```

Or (less restrictive):

```
//tr[@valign="top"]/td/span[contains(., 'Some Company')]
```

Comment: The value is not unique and it is a list, so I need that node of each table row. I tried your first example to no avail. Do single or double quotes matter? PHP wont let me use the ' without a \' in front of it. I cant see any ordering/formatting issues, as I copied the above row as it shows on the page source.

Comment: @savagenoob - Copied from the *actual* source, or from what Firebug showed you?

Comment: @savagenoob - Also, have you tried selecting by position? `//tr[@valign="top"]/td/span[1]`

Comment: @savagenoob - If you provide a more complete sample input, I'll try to provide a more accurate expression.

Comment: I realized that I used $html = @mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8'); when doing the cURL to get the page which changed the layout. Thanks for the help.